# How can I full text search response documents and have the parent show in the view/data table

Tags: full-text-search, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm at a bit of an impasse. I am working in Domino with xPages and I am trying to allow full text searching through a view including response documents but including the parent document for any responses that match the query in the view or data table.  Currently I'm just using the search term in a view datasource, and then using that datasource in a view control, but any workable solution would be welcome. There may be additional search criteria on the parent document.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard,
you can't directly use the view as data source, so you won't use the view control. You can use the data table or (probably better, since it gives you full layout control) the repeat control.

Run the search against the view in code:

```
   var v = database.getView("yourView")
   //var result = database.FTSearch(...)
   var result = v.FTSearchSorted(...) // or FTSearch
   var datasource = [];
   var parent;
   for (var doc in result) {
        addResult(doc, datasource);            
        if (doc.isResponseDoc()) {
            parent = doc.getParentDocument();
            addResult(parent, datasource);
            // Careful here - if the parent is part of the resultset on its own
            parent.recycle(); 
        }
        doc.recycle();
   }
   try {
      result.recycle();
      v.recycle();
   } catch (e) {
     // We suffer silently
   }
   return datasource;

   function addResult(doc, datasource) {
        var oneResult = {};
        //Adjust that to your needs
        oneResult.subject = doc.getItemValueString("Subject");
        oneResult.unid = doc.getUniversalId();
        datasource.push(oneResult);
   }
```

See the [FTSearchSorted](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/FTSearchSorted-Java_API) documentation. I typed the code off my head, so there might be little syntax snafus, ut you get the idea Don't return documents or Notes objects to the XPage and use recycle() wisely.

Comment: Thanks and yes I see where you're going here. Since the correct sort order will depend on the parent document, I won't get any benefit from FTSearchSorted, correct? I'll have to re-sort the datasource array and  will probably use some variation on a Java Collection then, and also handle re-sorting by column value myself (something managed well already in the view control).

Comment: Depends. If your view you search in e.g. doesn't have the property "show responses in a hierarchy" set, then responses are sorted on their own terms. If that does the trick for you, you can get around the Java collection. On the other hand with the compare options Java provides you, you have ultimate flexibility. Feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Well I was hoping the code fairy would come and leave DWIW (do what I want) package under my pillow but I can see I'll have to grind it out myself :-)